# Can "craving" refer to non-food desires?

Tags: word-usage

Usually the word craving refers to the wish to eat a certain foods. Can it also be used in other contexts? e.g. " I have a craving for Mozart" "I'm craving a comedy film"

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you? Did it say that it is limited to food?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a "craving" is **an intense desire for some particular thing, usually food, substance and activities.**

> - "an intense, urgent, or abnormal desire or longing"  [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craving)

e.g. "a craving for..."

- cocaine, heroin, tobacco, alcohol
- gambling, dangerous sports, adventure
- pickles, radish, turnips, crayfish, ice-cream, pizza, etc.
- sex, promiscuous sex

Some pregnant women experience bizarre food cravings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
As an ex-smoker I can definitively confirm I used to crave cigarettes / smoking!

Comment: Ah yes cigarettes of course, surprised I forgot such a common use of the word!

Answer (score 1):

"Craving" is often used in non-food contexts. Here is a use from the Odyssey, in the Harvard Classics [translation](http://www.bartleby.com/22/1.html):

> Now all the rest, as many as fled from sheer destruction, were at
>   home, and had escaped both war and sea, but Odysseus only, **craving** for
>   his wife and for his homeward path, the lady nymph Calypso held, that
>   fair goddess, in her hollow caves, longing to have him for her lord.

That said, according to the Google NGram viewer, craving is used much more rarely than "desiring" or "wanting."